# I want to get the Use% values from this individually. I used \d+% to get the values having %

Tags: regular-expression

I would like to match percentage in the next lines:

```
Filesystem 1K-blocks Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root 1503280 1388392 20476 99% /
/dev/mmcblk0p7 2753568 4616 2586036 1% /var/lib/docker
/dev/mmcblk0p5 463076 389578 43802 90% /var/volatile/log
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! It's not clear what your question is; please [edit] to clarify your goal and what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to escape `+`.

You can use: `\d\+%`

Comment: Or alternatively, you can add `\v` so more special characters have their special meaning without a backslash, but then you need to escape the `%`: `\v\d+\%`. Still, I find it convenient for more complex regexps as it more closely matches the behaviour in many programming languages and shell tools ("special meaning by default, escape for literal", rather than "escape for special meaning"). Also see `:help magic` for the docs on all of this.